# table inside table in Lua

Tags: lua, lua-table

How can I get the data which is a table inside a table, i mean like this:

```
t = { {a, b, c}, {d, e, f} };
```

if I write this line of code:

```
print( t[1] )
```

the result will be —–>>> {a, b, c}

BUT

how can I print just the letter “a”? without using `ipairs` I mean is there any way to use something like `t[1]`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried `t[1][1]`? That should get you the first index in the table you get from `t[1]`

Comment: Are you trying to print out the character 'a' or the value of the variable a? In the example you gave, a, b, c, d, e and f are variables, not characters, and if they haven't been initialized they'll be nil. If you want to print the character 'a' change your code to be `t = { {"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"} };`

Comment: Thank you very much Alex, appreciate your help. you'r right, you saved my life. 
But because you are very helpful, I want to ask you another question :).

if I have another table which contains just numbers like this:
table = { {1,2,3}, {4, 5, 6} }

how can I print 3? do we consider it as a variable too?

Thank you very very much,

Comment: No, the number 3 would not be a variable, it's simply a number. Variables are things you can set to different values (and different types). If you wanted to print 3 from that table, you would type `print(t[1][3])`, which gets third index from the first table. If you have not already, I suggest you read the online book ["Programming in Lua"](http://www.lua.org/pil/). The stuff you're asking about is mostly covered in the first two chapters. The book is fairly short, it shouldn't take more than a weekend to read through most of it.

Comment: Alex, You Are The Best.

Thank you