# Two index with one value in a lua table

Tags: multidimensional-array, lua, indexing, lua-table

I am very new to lua and my plan is to create a table. This table (I call it test) has 200 entries - each entry has the same subentries (In this example the subentries money and age):

This is a sort of pseudocode:

```
table test = {
    Entry 1: money=5 age=32
    Entry 2: money=-5 age=14
    ...
    Entry 200: money=999 age=72
}
```

How can I write this in lua ? Is there a possibility ? The other way would be, that I write each subentry as a single table:

```
table money = { }
table age = { }
```

But for me, this isn't a nice way, so maybe you can help me.

Edit:

This question [Table inside a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807969/table-inside-table-in-lua?rq=1) is related, but I cannot write this 200x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this syntax:

```
test = {
  { money = 5, age = 32 },
  { money = -5, age = 14 },
  ...
  { money = 999, age = 72 }
}
```

Examples of use:

```
-- money of the second entry:
print(test[2].money) -- prints "-5"

-- age of the last entry:
print(test[200].age) -- prints "72"
```

Comment: But how can I use the table without to write it 200x ? For example test[156].money = 5 and test[156].age = 99

Comment: @Albertus: I don't understand what you're asking for. What "it" are you trying not to "write 200x"?

Comment: @Albertus: `local t = test[156]; t.money = 5; t.age = 99`

Comment: @Albertus: If you write it like I said, you don't need to write it the way you said.

Answer (score 0):

You can also turn the problem on it's side, and have 2 sequences in `test`: `money` and `age` where each entry has the same index in both arrays.

```
test = {
   money ={1000,100,0,50},
   age={40,30,20,25}
}
```

This will have better performance since you only have the overhead of `3` tables instead of `n+1` tables, where `n` is the number of entries.

Anyway you have to enter your data one way or another. What you'd typically do is make use some easily parsed format like CSV, XML, ... and convert that to a table. Like this:

```
s=[[
1000 40
 100 30
   0 20
  50 25]]
test ={ money={},age={}}
n=1
for balance,age in s:gmatch('([%d.]+)%s+([%d.]+)') do
   test.money[n],test.age[n]=balance,age
   n=n+1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean you do not want to write "money" and "age" 200x?

There are several solutions but you could write something like:

```
local test0 = {
  5, 32,
  -5, 14,
  ...
}

local test = {}

for i=1,#test0/2 do
  test[i] = {money = test0[2*i-1], age = test0[2*i]}
end
```

Otherwise you could always use metatables and create a class that behaves exactly like you want.