# Lua tables within tables

Tags: lua, lua-table

```
local coordTable = {
    {loc={{1447, -2287, 13}, {0, 0, 3}, {100, -2000, 13}}, colour={255, 255, 255}},
}
```

Hi,

I'm trying to get each of the values from within loc. So, for each tables within loc, I want the value of the three numbers inside. I'm not sure if I'm explaining correctly.

Sort of like [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807969/table-inside-table-in-lua), but slightly more complex. I'm able to get the first table within loc using the same method in the issue linked above, but not the other tables.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What part do you need help with? `coordTable` is an array of coordinates, and the `loc` of each coordinate is an array of length-3 arrays.

Comment: I basically need to get the 3 numbers from each table within loc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps this helps you make sense of how to traverse the data:

```
for k,v in ipairs(coordTable[1].loc) do
    for i,w in ipairs(v) do
        print(k,i,w)
    end
end
```

Or that, if you always have three numbers in each subtable:

```
for k,v in ipairs(coordTable[1].loc) do
    print(v[1],v[2],v[3])
end
```

To get the three numbers in the second subtable directly, use

```
print(coordTable[1].loc[2][1],coordTable[1].loc[2][2],coordTable[1].loc[2][3])
```

Comment: "111447
12-2287
1313
210
220
233
31100
32-2000
3313
111447
12-2287
1313
210
220
233
31100
32-2000
3313" 

It returns the numbers, but in a weird way.

Comment: @user3549165, weird how? Anyway, perhaps my edited answer is clearer now.