# Multiple entries for one element of table in lua

Tags: lua

I am interested in inserting a table within a table in lua

```
mytable1={"apple","banana","grape"}
mytable2={"one","two","three"}
```

I want to insert `mytable2` in position 4 of `mytable1`... so after the merger it should look somewhat like this

```
mytable1={"apple","banana","grape",{"one","two","three"}}
```

So far I tried it this way:

```
table.insert(mytable1,4,mytable2)
print(mytable[4])
```

the result is 
`table: 0x900b128` instead of `mytable2`..
I am quite confused.Please advice me where I am doing wrong and what is the right way to proceed.

Comment: What about that output do you think is wrong? `print` doesn't print out keys and values of tables it just prints `table: 0xXXXXXXX` which is the id of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've done it correctly; You're just making incorrect assumptions about values, variables and print.

`mytable2` is a variable name. You generally won't see variable names as strings except if you are debugging.

A table is a value. No value has a name. `table.insert` adds a value (or value reference) to a table. In this case, the value is a table so a reference to it is added to the table referenced by the `mytable1` variable.

`print` calls `tostring` on its arguments. `tostring` on a table value returns what amounts to a unique identifier. `print(mytable2)` would print the same string as `print(mytable1[4])` because both reference the same table.

Answer (score 1):

Is possible:

```
tTable = { "apple", "banana", "grape", {"one", "two", "three"}}
tTable[1]
> apple
tTable[4][1]
> one
```

Print on table does not return it's values, but the indication that's it is a table and it's address.

Source: [table inside table in Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807969/table-inside-table-in-lua)

Suppose you want to simply display everything in your table:

```
tTable = { "apple", "banana", "grape", {"one", "two", "three"}}

for k,v in pairs(tTable) do
  if type(k) == "table" then
    for _,i in ipairs(k) do
      print(i)
    end
  else
    print(v)
  end
end
> apple 
> banana
> grape
> one
> two
> three
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how printing of a table works. Try out `print(mytable1)` or `print(mytable2)` and you see a similar output. You used the correct way of inserting that table. Just try out `print(table1[4][1])`. it should print `"one"`

Or to get all values try:

```
for index, value in ipairs(table1[4]) do
  print(value);
end
```

this will print `"one"`, `"two"` and "`three"`